# Chrome screen resoultion is different then the device resolution

Tags: google-chrome, resolution, screen-resolution

The resoution of my notebook is 2880X1620. But somehow its 1440x810 in Chrome based on https://www.whatismyscreenresolution.org/. I've got an other monitor connected to my device, which has the resolution 1920x1080. For this monitor the resolution in the Windows and in the Chrome is the same.

Why is the resolution of the main screen is the half in the notebook?